# Cannot update UI object's frame in UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have a subclassed UITableViewCell.

I need to dynamically change the frame of a UILabel.

Here's what I've done:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"messageCell";
    MessageCell *cell = (MessageCell*) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.Content.Text = @"Content!";
    [cell.Content setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 10)];
}
```

The text of the UILabel does change so this is not an IBOutlet issue.
The frame however remains the same as was defined in IB.

I've done stuff like this before so I'm not really sure what went wrong here...

Thanks for any help.

**Edit:**

I use

```
[self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"MessageCell" bundle:nil]
     forCellReuseIdentifier:@"MessageCell"];
```

in viewDidLoad

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well a few days after posting the bounty I've found the answer, I hope this will help someone someday...

I am not 100% sure why, but what I tried to do simply can not be done:

**You cannot change the frame of an object if you've put it through Interface Builder.**

To make the changes I wanted to do, I simply created those objects programmatically in my subclass, inside "initWithCoder".

```
content = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(120, 100, 200, 50)];
content.opaque = NO;
content.numberOfLines = 0;
[self.contentView addSubview:content];
```

I was then able to change the frames inside "- (void)layoutSubviews" (but basically anywhere I wanted)

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    [cell.Content setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 10)];

    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

There must be something wrong there.

Try, ***just*** ***for testing*** to implement this:

```
tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:
```

Like

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell    forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MessageCell* aCell = (MessageCell*)cell;
    aCell.Content.Text = @"Content!";
    [aCell.Content setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 10)];
}
```

What's the result?

Comment: Great Daniel it worked for me.
Finally you gave a solution to a very known problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can not edit frame of UI object created through xib if Autolayout is on.
There are two ways to do this:

1. Disable Autolayout for that xib.

OR

2. Make an IBOutlet for particular NSlayout constraint attach it accordingly and update its constant property value through code and don't forget to call layOutIfNeeded appropriately on the object on which constarint is implemented or superview as per implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Add a subview to `cell.Content` and resize that subview instead of the content itself. The cell will always be stretched to fit in your table view so you can't make it smaller.
(and of course to make the cell height smaller just apply `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`)

Comment: I didn't try editing the view of the cell, but a UILabel inside that cell.

Answer (score 1):

May be this relates to fact of reusing cell. Try this

```
  - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"messageCell";
        MessageCell *cell = (MessageCell*) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if(cell == nil)
       { 
        cell = [[[MessageCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier]autorelease];
        }
        cell.Content.Text = @"Content!";
        [cell.Content setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 10)];
        return cell;
    }
```

Comment: Have you set the datasource of your tableview ? What you mean by app not reaching (cell == nil), is cellForRowAtIndexPath gets called?

Comment: Then where you are allocating your cell?

Comment: it's loaded from the storyboard

Comment: I use [self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"MessageCell" bundle:nil]
         forCellReuseIdentifier:@"MessageCell"];

Answer (score 1):

Did you consider overriding the `- (void) layoutSubviews` method in your custom cell (i.e. MessageCell) and layout your stuff in there? I think this is the safest place to put layout changing code in, because in other places it may not have any effect. Don't forget to call `[super layoutSubviews];` in your implementation of `layoutSubviews`.

Consider going with this approach and let us know if it worked out for you!
But you need to consider performance implications with this approach, because `layoutSubviews` will be called every time the table scrolls.

EDIT:

to accommodate for the right frame size for your label inside `layoutSubviews` consider using `- (CGSize)sizeWithFont:(UIFont *)font constrainedToSize:(CGSize)size lineBreakMode:(UILineBreakMode)lineBreakMode` for the frame calculation.

Comment: Still not getting any result...
I made sure the overridden layoutSubviews in MessageCell is being called, and I also called the super function

Comment: Another very awkward attempt: override the "- (void) setFrame: (CGRect) frame" method in your MessageCell.m (call super once again) and put a NSLog statement in there to see when it's called during the table view redraw cycle!

Comment: And another question regarding my initial answer: in your overridden "layoutSubviews" method, when do you call "[super layoutSubviews]"? Try putting the call to super AFTER you've set the frame for your label.

Comment: Tried putting the call both after and before.
If I put it before, I have just noticed that if I call [self.tableview reloadData], the cell will update. But not while scrolling

Comment: I'm having a very similar problem. I nearly solved it by creating the UILabel programatically in the  - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath and adding [cell addSubview:myLabel]; - but I got duplicates of the uilabel appearing when scrolling

Comment: The duplicates appear probably because you're adding the label also in case of cell reuse, so the label objects stack up with every cell reuse cycle!