# IOS uiview frame didn't update

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

Hi I tried to assign new frame size to the separator uiview, but it doesn't change, i dunno why, I tried to debug and the newFrame have a new value but after assign to separator, the separator seem like never receive the new value

```
UIView *separator = (UIView *)[cell viewWithTag: 10];
CGRect newFrame;
    if(lblBuyPrice.frame.origin.x > lblBuyQuantity.frame.origin.x){
        newFrame = CGRectMake( lblBuyQuantity.frame.origin.x, separatorBuy.frame.origin.y, lblBuyQuantity.frame.size.width, separatorBuy.frame.size.height);
    }else{
        newFrame = CGRectMake( lblBuyPrice.frame.origin.x, separatorBuy.frame.origin.y, lblBuyPrice.frame.size.width, separatorBuy.frame.size.height);
    }
    separatorBuy.frame = newFrame;
```

the uiview element is inside a cell

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27874784/3802077

Comment: element inside a cell is unable to make a IBOutlet link

Comment: are you not using a custom class? I dont like using extra nibs but this is an example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19314715/3802077

Comment: What's the context? Where this assignment is made? Is AutoLayout enabled or not? Do you have layoutSubviews implementation for your superview?

Comment: I have solved by putting identifier for the constraint and use a loop to search the width in the constraint member